# Secure route in HTTPS Laravel

Tags: forms, laravel, security, https, routes

In a view page I have this route:
`<form action="{{ route('unisharp.lfm.upload') }}" role='form' id='uploadForm' name='uploadForm' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`

With HTTPS I get a 'mixed-content error'. How can I get a secure route?

Comment: Laravel uses the current scheme to create urls. Is your webpage loaded over https?

Comment: Yes, For Assets links is used ,true and that works fine. Only the route in my view doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use secure_url() instead of route(), this will replace action URL with secure one.
[Helper function - secure_url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-secure-url)